# Why data isn't being added to array in NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js

What is wrong with my code:

```
var emailExistence = require('email-existence');

var emails = ['klevisi@gmail.com', 'workingemail@gmail.com'];
var validEmails = [];


emails.forEach(function(email) {
    emailExistence.check(email, function(err, res) {
        if(res == true) {
            validEmails.push(email); //No email is being added
            console.log(email); //Emails are written to the console
        }
    });
});

validEmails.forEach(function(email) {
    console.log(email); //Nothing is written to the console
});
```

The validEmails array isn't being populated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: In addition to wrong way of checking results of asynchronous method there is very good possibility that gmail and other open servers will simply refuse to provide information need for "email-existence" to detect valid e-mail addresses.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did some testing, and this script returns true when passing valid emails, but I believe that some servers will refuse to provide this information.

Comment: @thefourtheye I just want to know why the array validEmails doesn't fill with data using validEmails.push(email).

Comment: @KlevisMiho Did you check the linked dup post?

Comment: @thefourtheye sure thanks, but I am new to Nodejs and this post is too overwhelming for me.

Comment: @KlevisMiho Trust me, its worth spending a day on it. Its a must read for all of us :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye seems like it's worth a read, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because

```
validEmails.forEach(function(email) {
console.log(email); //printed at last
});
```

is outside the callback.So it executed before executing the callback.You will have to use `validEmails` after every thing has been added or all callback completed.

You can use [underscore's after](http://underscorejs.org/#after) for these kind of things.

you can try with

```
var _U = require('underscore');
var afterAllEmailChecks = _U.after(emails.length,function(){
    validEmails.forEach(function(email) {
        console.log(email); //Nothing is written to the console
    });
});
emails.forEach(function(email) {
    emailExistence.check(email, function(err, res) {
        if(res == true) {
            validEmails.push(email); //No email is being added
            console.log(email); //Emails are written to the console
        }
       afterAllEmailChecks();
    });
});
```

Comment: is it possible for you to edit my function so the logic works? As I am still having trouble on how to do that.

Comment: modified my answer.Try it.